# taking date with jquery calendar and send to mvc

Tags: c#, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have in my view Datetime fied like these

```
 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.StartDate)
 <input type="button" id="pickDate" value="Send date" />
```

Jquery datepicker is implement and I'm using DateTime.cshtml inside shared folder like these

```
@model DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString("d|M|yyyy"),
   new { @class = "date" })

$('#pickDate').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

            url: '/Home/DateManipulation',
            success: function (result) { alert('Success');},
            error: function () { alert("error"); }
   });
});

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DateManipulation()
{
  DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(Request.Params["MyDate"], "d|M|yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

   var data = //process some other manipulation with data      
   return Json(data);
}
```

Question is: how to send date using above js script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieve value of the `StartDate` input field and pass it as a `data` to the ajax request.

```
$('#pickDate').click(function () {
    var date = $('input[name="StartDate"]').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: {date: date},
            url: '/Home/DateManipulation',
            success: function (result) { alert('Success');},
            error: function () { alert("error"); }
   });
});
```

And on server side you can specify the corresponding parameter for action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DateManipulation(string date)
{
    DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "d|M|yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    var data = //process some other manipulation with data      
    return Json(data);
}
```